# Как кодируется строка в байты

Tags: c#, кодировка, байты

Каким образом набор символов преобразуется в байты? Допустим из этого кода:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("actress.txt");
using(StreamWriter sw = fi.CreateText()) {
  sw.WriteLine("Hello");
  sw.Write("World");

}

byte[] byfiles = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);
using(StreamWriter sw = fi.CreateText()) {
  foreach(byte task in byfiles) {
    sw.WriteLine(task);
  }
}
```

Получается набор таких байтов:

```
72
101
108
108
111
13
10
87
111
114
108
100
```

Comment: Почитайте про текстовые кодировки, Unicode например.

Comment: В данном случае все символы входят в набор ASCII.

Comment: Например 13 10 соответствует переносу строки или строке из двух escape-символов`"\r\n"`. Для преобразования символов в байты и обратно используется таблица символов, в вашем случае ASCII.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, какой именно ответ вам нужен? Теория, или помочь с решением какой-то конкретной практической задачи?

Comment: Просто теорию. Изучив понял что каждый байт в том наборе соответствует букве в Юникоде. Но теперь назрел другой вопрос, неужели вся система включает в себя только 255 символов?

Comment: @luc1f, 256 символов было только "на заре времён" в наборе ASCII. В Unicode же тысячи символов (всего он может вместить 65536)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто. Перейдите на [этот](http://www.asciitable.com/) сайт и сопоставьте байт с значением символа, получите ваш текст. `13 10` = `\r\n` – перенос на новую линию (aka CRLF). Данный набор байтов представлен в UTF8 кодировке, т. к. это стандартная кодировка у `StreamWriter`.

---

Правильно:

```cs
using var stream = File.OpenWrite("file.txt");
using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
writer.WriteLine("Привет, мир!");
```

Неправильно:

```cs
using var stream = File.OpenWrite("file.txt");
using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.WriteLine("Привет, мир!"); // кодируется не правильно
```